# Struggling to show data in a label between custom classes and the view controller

Tags: swift, xcode

This is in my viewController

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



var numberInCircleView: NumberInCircleView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {

    self.numberInCircleView = NumberInCircleView(frame: .zero)
    self.view.addSubview(self.numberInCircleView)
    self.numberInCircleView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in

        make.leading.equalTo(20)
        make.bottom.equalTo(-40)
        make.width.equalTo(60)
        make.height.equalTo(60)
    }
    self.numberInCircleView.numberLabel = 5
}

}
```

The following is in my custom class.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class NumberInCircleView: UIView {



 var numberLabel: UILabel!




override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.setupViews()
}


func setupViews() {


    self.numberLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    self.addSubview(self.numberLabel)
    self.numberLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.numberLabel.text = ""
    self.numberLabel.textAlignment = .center
    self.numberLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    self.numberLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.numberLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
}
```

This line in my ViewController

```
    self.numberInCircleView.numberLabel = 5
```

Should set the label as 5. I'm not sure how I call between views to do this? Could you please advise? Some online tutorials that offer me more info on this would be much appreciated too.

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to set the value 5 to the label but here you are missing the proper syntax, the `numberLabel` is a `UILabel` instance and has the property `text` of type `String` if you want to set the text to the label you have to assign some string like this:

```
self.numberInCircleView.numberLabel.text = "5"
```

Answer (score 0):

`I'm not sure how I call between views to do this`
You can call any method on any object till you have a reference to it.

`self.numberInCircleView.numberLabel = 5` this is compile time error , as you can't assign 5 to type of "UILabel"

Replace 
`self.numberInCircleView.numberLabel = 5`

with

`self.numberInCircleView.numberLabel.text = "5"`